# Read/Write Capacity Unit in AWS DynamoDB - Price per hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have recently explored AWS DynamoDB and was reading about Read/Write Capacity Units. I understood that they are as under:

- [WCU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Write): A write capacity unit represents one write per second, for
  an item up to 1 KB in size.
- [RCU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Read): A read capacity unit represents
  one strongly consistent read per second, or two eventually consistent
  reads per second, for an item up to 4 KB in size.

So, my table has 1 WCU and 1 RCU. This means I would be charged for every read and every write I do to my table. Good so far. Plus I would be charged additionally for data storage.

However, when I look at [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) (scroll down to DynamoDB detailed feature pricing/Read and Write Requests), it shows me WCU and RCU in Price per hour which is $0.00065 per WCU or $0.00013 per RCU.

**What is the meaning or Price per hour?**

Would I be wrong to assume $0.00065 per WCU or $0.00013 per RCU and ignore the hour part completely? Meaning, per write would cost me $0.00065 and per read would cost me $0.00013.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pricing models for DynamoDB: Provisioned and On-Demand.

[Provisioned capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) means that you will be charged each hour for the provisioned unit whether you consume it or not -- and your requests will be throttled if you go over provisioned capacity in a given second.  This model allows for considerable savings when you have stable demand and you have a method within your solution to deal with throttles gracefully.

If you are in the dev mode, or your application has unpredictable peaks, you should consider [On-Demand mode](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) where you will be billed a flat rate per request irrespectively of the rate of requests.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Would I be wrong to assume $0.00065 per WCU or $0.00013 per RCU and ignore the hour part completely? Meaning, per write would cost me $0.00065 and per read would cost me $0.00013.

Yes, for this configuration you would be charged as follows:

##### Writes

`$0.00065 * 730 = $0.4745 per month`

##### Reads

`$0.00013 * 730 = $0.0949 per month`

---

In provisioned mode you pay for the capacity regardless of how many requests you make. Having 1WCU and 1RCU will allow you to write 1 * 1KB items per second and read 1 * 4KB per second. Moreover, DynamoDB free tier allows you 25WCU and 25RCU per region per month. You can apply this capacity to a single table or multiple tables as you wish. This is enough capacity to provide 200M requests per month.

In contrast, On-demand mode allows you to pay per request, however it's not as cost effective as provisioned mode. It simplifies using DynamoDB without needing to think about setting capacity or auto-scaling. It does not have a free tier.

DynamoDB free tier also provides 25GB of storage per month per region.

Have a look over the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html)… it's filled with valuable information to help you understand the difference in capacity modes.

Comment: "In provisioned mode you pay for the capacity regardless of how many requests you make.". This means if I have 1 RCU/WCU in a single table, I would be indicatively charged how much ? IMO I would be charged $0.00065 per WCU every hour.

Comment: What is the number 730 in the formula pls?

Comment: 730 is number of hours in a month. Yes , the cost of provisioned mode is hourly and on a monthly basis.

Comment: 24 hours per day x 30 days in a month = 720 hours in a month. Why 730?

Comment: `365 days X 24 hours / 12 months = 730 hours`.

Comment: "Moreover, DynamoDB free tier allows you 25WCU and 25RCU per region per month. " I have 1 RCU/WCU in a table. So for 25 days I won't be charged? And how did you conclude this is enough for 200M requests a month pls?

Comment: You won't be charged at all. You can have 25 of each for free, you're only using 1. 2628002 seconds in a month, 1 WCU allows you to make a request each second. 1 RCU allows you 2 eventually consistent reads per second.