# Does the cost of writing N records into a DynamoDB table is the same, irrespective of the write duration?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, throughput, cost-management

This question considers a provisioned capacity with autoscaling. This is a very basic question to better understand WCU/RCU pricing.

I'm not quite sure of the answer because it appears that provisioning a high throughput for a short period might be more expensive (i.e. require more resource reservation) than provisioning a low throghput in a long period of time.

I have a huge workload to import into a DynamoDB table (~1 billion records) and I want to understand if I could increase the throughput to reduce the time needed for the operation to finish, understanding if that would incur in the same price.

Example: will using 5000 WCU for 1 minute incur the same cost as using 5 WCU for 1000 minutes?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501545/read-write-capacity-unit-in-aws-dynamodb-price-per-hour) seems to be very similar but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost is per WCU-hour with billing per hour. Provisioning 100,000 for 5 hours or 50,000 for 10 hours results in the same WCU-hr consumption.